# How to Use Where clause in get API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, get

I am creating API to Get Data from Table.
My table is Tbl_Menu.

```
      Id      MenuName     Status
-----------------------------------------------------
        1    idli            True
        2    Utappa          false
        3    MeduWada       True
```

i want data in API GET having only Status = true.

My Get API is

```
public IEnumerable<Tbl_Menu> GetTbl_Menu()
        {
            var tbl_menu = db.Tbl_Menu;
            return tbl_menu.AsEnumerable();
        }
```

I have to use **Where** Clause.
so what changes I suppose to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var tbl_menu = db.Tbl_Menu;
return tbl_menu.Where(t=> t.Status == true).ToList();
```